# In Ubuntu, is it a good idea to launch eclipse with sudo?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, root

I used maven to download mahout and hadoop recently. Because I could not seem to do that without using sudo mvn commands, eclipse could not seem to be able to use anything I had downloaded (there were lots of errors like parents of things like POM.xml being permission denied etc.) and more recently than that I was trying out mahout (with local jars downloaded directly from one of apache's mirrors, not from maven) and although I could run the class the first time, I couldn't do it again because my eclipse instance could not overwrite the file I had already written.

These are just examples of times I feel it would have been good to be running eclipse as superuser by doing

```
sudo eclipse
```

Instead of just launching it normally. The only problem I can think of is that as root eclipse suggests you use the root/workspace, but is it ok to just tell it to use yourusername/workspace?

Answer (score 3):

In general- no.  It's tempting, but not very good practice to do all of your development as the superuser.  If you're running Eclipse as root, then you're also launching Java processes as root when you run your software.  (You could change your Java run settings to `sudo` back to a regular user before running, but I wouldn't recommend that as a solution).

In addition to being a security risk, you are also making it difficult to track down bugs if you want to distribute the software to others to run as non-root (*e.g.* doing root only things like reading a protected file or using a well known port might work for you, but not for the average user).

I recommend finding the files that are causing issues and doing `chmod o+r` on them.

Comment: Right. I don't suppose you have any idea why it is that whenever I try and go to a directory and do 
    'mvn install'
it won't let me, and I have to use sudo? No online guides that I have seen state this will be a problem, and I always/usually just copy the exact paths they recommend. It's usually /opt.

Comment: Typically `/opt` is writable only by root. If you're running `mvn install` from the shell, and you want to install to `/opt`, just run `sudo mvn install`. Installing typically requires root; editing, compiling, and linking do not.

Comment: But if you run     sudo mvn install 
then root did the install and the normal user account instance of eclipse can't do anything with the files. How is it everyone else seems to avoid this problem?